# Import strategy built in IB API to IB Trader Workstation

Tags: interactive-brokers

Is there any way to import strategies built in the IB API to Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation (TWS)?

Answer (score 0):

No.  That's the whole purpose of having an API.  TWS is used for trading manually.  The API can be used to automate strategies.

Comment: Does TWS support importing strategies just like Wealth-Lab does?

Comment: Not TWS, but something like ninja trader that uses the api can import strategies.